# Улучшенный тест AKS.

Tags: алгоритм, c, c++

Прочитал, что тест Агравала — Каяла — Саксены был улучшен некоторыми умельцами так, что время его работы требует не O(log^7.5(n)), а O(log^3(n)).
Нигде в интернете не нашел нормлаьного кода с более-менее понятными объяснениями работы(может быть, я просто плохо искал)

Не мог бы кто-нибудь привести пример реализации данного теста с пояснениями, почему оно работает?
Реализацию желательно на с/c++, но вообще пойдет любой язык=)

Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/qa/7255/ тут ссылки некоторые полезные указаны, может быть найдется что-то полезное. на глаз оценить эффективность алгоритма O(log^7.5(n)) от O(log^3(n)) отличить не так просто...

Comment: а пробовали зайти в русскую википедию, пролистать в самый низ и посмотреть список ссылок? по одной я нашел реализацию на java (хотя она и в виде jar файла, но там внутри есть и исходники, не знаю, все ли), по другой ссылку на pdf  с описанием работы алгоритма.